# Mysql Full Text Searching - How to require all search terms

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have this search query:

```
SELECT id, MATCH(names) AGAINST('Tom Smith') AS score FROM content WHERE MATCH(names) AGAINST('Tom Smith') ORDER BY SCORE DESC
```

It returns 246 rows with anything the contains `'Tom Smith', 'Tom (any initial) Smith', 'Tom' or 'Smith'`.

Is there a way to have the query return rows with just 'Tom Smith', 'Tom T. Smith', 'Tom Robert Smith' etc?

Basically, rows that must contain Tom AND Smith, but not  any rows that only contain just 'Tom' or just 'smith'?

However I don't just want rows that contain only 'Tom Smith', rows that contain 'Tom (any word) Smith' are fine too.

I imagine this is possible,  however, I am having trouble getting results that also contain the 'Tom (any word) Smith' criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Somedays, my brain doesn't work too well :) Forgot about boolean mode

```
SELECT id, MATCH(names) AGAINST('+Tom +Smith' IN BOOLEAN MODE ) AS score FROM content WHERE MATCH(names) 
AGAINST('+Tom +Smith' IN BOOLEAN MODE ) ORDER BY SCORE DESC
```